# How to add Navigation bar programmatically by clicking the button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have Login, Signup and Reset viewControllers I have connected the UINavigation controller to login controller but when I go to other view controllers by clicking the button like `signup` or `reset password` the destination controller appears without navigation bar. help to include navigation bar programmatically when I click the below button.

```
@IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: Any) {
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For display navigation bar you need to add your  `SignUpViewController` in `UINavigationController` you can add directly in storyboard By

**Selecting SignUpViewController -> Editor Menu -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller**

**OR**

you can add programmatically  like this

```
IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: Any) {
     let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
     let naviCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController:newViewController)
     self.present(naviCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much dear @jignesh Vadadoriya

Comment: you are wel come